# Is it possible to specify a numeric format used in a chart legend?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, format, legend

I am creating a surface chart in VBA. All three axes have dynamic ranges. Is there a way to define the numeric format used in the legend so that it does not display so many decimal places? For example
[image]

I tried

```
.HasLegend = True
.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
.Legend.Font.Size = 12 ' new in version 50
.Legend.format = "0.00"
```

but setting the format property fails.

Comment: `Legend` is a text string and does not have a `NumberFormat` property. You would need to change it at the source.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That's it. Thank you.